# Windows Server 2008 SBS restarts on startup after crash. How to repair it?

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

Our server restart every time I am trying to start it. After a power loss it hadn't enough time to shutdown correctly. I already tried "Load last working configuration" and "Avoid restart on error" in the F8 startup menu.

Is there any other thing I can try to get it working? I can boot it to the save mode but don't know what to do in there to fix it.

Comment: Do you happen to be running AVG anti-virus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the issue and you wouldn't believe it. After the server crashed, we used the oppertunity to change the USV battery. With the new battery the USV reported that everything is fine.

But actually because the battery haven't been loaded to 100% for the first time it keeps sending "shut server down" messages over the network. The strange thing was, that only one server was shutting down while the other server keeps running.

I found that out connecting only my own PC to the server and than adding additional clients. As soon as the USV was connected (which was the last client) the server shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from the installation CD and running a repair.

Also, if you are able to get into safe mode, you can try going into msconfig, and disable everything in the Startup and Services tab and attempt a normal reboot. If it comes up, start selectively adding those items back in until it fails again.